# How get value form config file?

Tags: c#, .net

How to get different types(int, bool, string, long, etc.) of values from the config file in c#?

Values are stored in `properties -> settings`.

Comment: Are you talking about `appsettings.json`?

Comment: please check [four ways to handle](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/01/05/4-easy-steps-to-custom-sections-in-web-config/) the `exe.config` sections. The idea is that you can define custom class and use deserialization to get class instance from the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple answer i got is

```
int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Settings.Default["value1"].ToString());
long value2 = Convert.ToInt64(Settings.Default["value2"].ToString());
string value3 = Settings.Default["value3"].ToString();
bool value4 =  Convert.ToBoolean(Settings.Default["value4"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are creating a Windows forms app and your project properties has a Settings tab showing a grid with 4 columns; name, type, scope and value. In code you write:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.YourPropertyName
```

For example if you have a setting

```
Name     Type     Value
MaxAge   double   100
```

Then you can have code:

```
_ageNumericUpDown.MaxValue = Properties.Settings.Default.MaxAge;
```

The difference between application scope and user scope settings is that user scope can be modified by the code (`Properties.Settings.Default.MaxAge = 200;`) and saved with `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`. Application scope settings have to be modified by editing the YourExeName.exe.config XML file. User scope settings are not stored in this file, they are stored in a similar shaped file somewhere in the user temp data folders, in case you ever wonder why save doesn't alter the main settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out

If your Config file like this(xml) WebAppSettings.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="name" value="John"/>
</appSettings>
```

In C# we call get the value from the WebAppSettings.config

```
var value= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
```

out put

John

Comment: the problem is that values are strings (so you will need to convert them to int or datetime whatever) and this attempt allows only primitive types.